# Why my site not linking with google.com?

Tags: google-search

i am very tired about my website ranking in google. i am dong hard work about it but not getting anywhere my site in google. actually i am web master of a www.panbeli.in matrimony website INDIA. i am trying to improve its visibility in google last 5 month but not getting any positive result. but other search engine giving good result like yahoo and bing but google showing no any result in top 20 page result.
my website is www.panbeli.in
and my keyword are-
bari samaj
bari matrimony
bari community
bari shadi
panbeli
please help me if you can, b'coz i am very frustrated about it.
my domain age is 4 years
when i type link:panbeli.in  in google search
does not appear any pages from my site in google.
whats the meaning is that?my site does not indexed in google?

Comment: Do you have a site map? Do you have a robots.txt file?

Comment: Sorry but we can't do SEO reviews here. If you want your site to rank better read the questions and answers in the [seo tag](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) on tis site.

Answer (score 0):

Learn SEO. It's not something you do within a single day. It's a practice involves your code, content, presentation, distribution and many other things. Different search engines have different SEO policies / methodologies.

Since you're concerned about Google start learning how google likes to have your website. What does it expect and how should you present your website to it. Just do a research on these topics and you would know why your site doesn't get better results.

First, sign up for http://www.google.com/webmasters/ then try optimising your site according to Google SEO norms. Try this starter guide at the beginning http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf